# Size of ArrayList

Tags: java

I am having an arrayList of arraylist Like this

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Byte> > shares = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Byte> >();
```

I want to find number of rows in this ArrayList and Number of columns in each of row list also.How to do it.

Please help.

Comment: And what do you want to do with these values, once you get them? Print them out? Store them somewhere? What have you tried?

Comment: @wakjah I need to store them.Am getting NullPointerException while doing it.So i posted it on SO

Comment: Please provide stack traces if you encounter exceptions.

Comment: Please provide code which we could use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Remember that each inner ArrayList may have different size, that could be the reason for `NullPointerException`. You cannot assume the size of inner ArrayList without querying it by using the size() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`int List.size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size%28%29) does exist. Use it.

```
int rows = shares.size();
for (List<Byte> row : shares) {
    int columns = row.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine the list size use:

```
shares.size();
```

To determine a specific size use:

```
shares.get(index).size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `ArrayList<Byte>` in `shares` represents a row. So the total number of rows is `shares.size()`, and number of columns in row `i` is equal to the length of the `ArrayList<Byte>` at position `i`, which is `shares.get(i).size()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is `shares.size()` => the number list in the list shares

```
for(int i = 0;i<shares.size();++i){
    shares.get(i).size();// the size of each arraylist in the list shares
}
```